Is "secco" really used in piano music?
Secco is Italian for dry. Many sources define the term within the context of recitativo secco, i.e. with sparse accompaniment. Wikipedia describes an appropriate realization for basso continuo.
Two select sources, including this forum and a comment on my own Music.SE question, suggest (confidently) that this term is also used in piano music to mean playing without pedal and/or staccato. The first of those includes a published example...of a Brazilian composer writing sec., likely for Portuguese seco.
Apart from these, I can only find references to recitativo secco. Is this actually an established term in piano music? Are there more sources showing its use or discussing its intent?
The literal translation points in the right direction, but I don't like to make a habit of using music terms that can't be googled, and this one is barely hanging on.

I've never seen it. If it's used, it's only rarely, or perhaps in editions of specific languages.

@Aaron I first encountered this term in a composition by a namesake of yours, though I recall it being in the string parts rather than the piano part.  I'll see if I can find it again.

Slightly off-piste, but in guitar-speak, 'dry' is the original guitar sound with no added effects, particularly reverb/echo.

@Tim in the classical choral world at least (and probably in most other areas) one often speaks of "dry" acoustics, that is, a room or hall with little reverb.  For example, one might point out that the acoustic will be drier when there are people sitting in the seats.  You sometimes also hear "wet" to mean the opposite, though this seems slightly less common.

In Bartók’s Mikrokosmos, Vol. V, No. 124 Staccato, there’s the instruction secco quasi pizz., meaning that the staccato is particularly dry/short (like plucked strings).  Hear a rendition by the composer himself.

I had a European orchestral conductor who always used to ask for "secco, super secco" to indicate a very short staccato.

Lubomyr Melnyk refers to pedal-less playing as "dry" periods, he just doesn't use the Italian word for it.

I. Examples of secco meaning "dry" or with no (or very little) pedal in piano music:

Last measure of Gottschalk's Le bananier, Op.5

 
Piano part (m.18 and m.91) in the 4th movement (Tocata) of Villa-Lobos' Bachianas Brasileiras Nº 2

The constant rhythmic base played by the piano, added of indications of
secco (staccato) (m.18) and secco senza Pedale (mm.91ff.), is punctuated by the celesta interventions of staccato chords ...
Norton Dudeque; Heitor Villa-Lobos’s Bachianas Brasileiras
(2021)




Ernesto Nazareth, Odeon, Tango Brasileiro, m.8 and m.21

Josef Hofmann answered a question about Moskowski's Etude Op.72 n.6 m.29:


"Secco" means "dry." It is a characterization of tone, not of the
manner of playing. If you roll a chord and do it with a dry touch,
with a sharp staccato and without pedal, it will be "secco" and
distinct from an arpeggio played with a legato touch, by which you
would hold all the notes until the whole chord is complete
"Piano
Questions Answered by Josef Hofmann" in Ladies' Home Journal  Vol.
33 (1916)



Béla Bartók, Mikrokosmos No.124

No. 124: The tempo chosen is slow enough to accommodate the required
finger staccato for the "secco, quasi pizz." touch.
David Yeomans;
Bartók for Piano (2000)



"What a Wonderful World"; Words and music by George David Weiss and Bob Thiele. Arr. Mike Springer See m.46 and m.54.

II. References to secco in discussions of piano music:

 Joseph Banowetz; The
Pianist's Guide to Pedaling (1985)


Performance direction
19. Piano: Senza Ped(ale), secco means without (sustaining)
pedal, dry (ie staccato).
Paul Terry and ‎David Bowman; Student's
Guide to A2 Music (2004)


Piece VII [of Stockhausen's Piano Pieces] is in five
tempo-defined sections ... Its most interesting feature is the
definition of favored resonances by silently-depressed keys (the
lozenge-shaped notes in the score), regions set in reverberation by
accented single notes. The aim is to turn the piano into a flexible,
selective resonator, and the resonant character of the piece evolves
organically and with the same deliberation as the active notes and
groups... The combination of manual and pedal sustain creates a rich
resource of resonance possibilities, from secco through to
indefinite sustain.
Robin Maconie; Other Planets  (2016)


Intermittences and Caténaires, composed for two top-flight pianists...This nocturn-like work explores the resonating aspect of
the piano through a variety of pedal effects. Phrases are played
secco, without pedal; sustained, without pedal; sustained with the sostenuto (middle) pedal; and sustained with the right pedal
David Schiff; Carter (2018)


Continue also to use the sustaining pedal fully until measures 55 to
56, where you may have enough cluster sonority left to let you play
the staccato notes high above truly secco. If that doesn't work,
play those notes secco and in addition put the sustaining pedal down
on the second sixteenth-count of that beat.
Bradford Gowen; A
Performer's Guide to the Piano Music of Samuel Adler (2022)


Many nineteenth-century composers relied on pianists to refer to the
then-prevailing performance practice concerning pedaling. They
reserved pedal indications for exceptional circumstances, giving an
indication to depress the damper pedal over multiple measure to blur
several harmonies together or to play senza pedal to confirm a
secco sound.
Alan Shockley; The Contemporary Piano (2018)


Much of the piano writing in the finales of [Faure's] opus 13 and opus
15 equally suits secco or light dabs, the string instruments
providing a sustaining 'orchestra' against which the piano can
sparkle. Ravel's Concertos show similar distinct contrasts between
highly pedalled episodes, notably when the piano is unaccompanied, and
sparkling passages against orchestra that invite minimal (if
any) pedal.
Roy Howat; The Art of French Piano Music (2009)


sec (French 'dry') term used by some French composers, especially Debussy, where a note or chord is to be struck and released again
abruptly without any richness of tone.
Barrie Jones; The Hutchinson
Concise Dictionary of Music (1999)


The rehabilitation of the piano among the orchestral instruments,
where indeed it had begun in the days of Haydn, rested partly on its
quality of secco articulation, partly on its ability to lend
colour to its surroundings.
...
In Movements the piano, always
secco without pedals, often confined to just single notes in each hand, is shown off in different instrumental contexts, as the voices
had been in Threni, written the year before.
Francis Routh; "Stravinsky's piano works"


Also cited in another answer: Beethoven uses secco with another meaning (ie without arpeggio) at the close of the second movement of his "Appassionata" Sonata (Wallner/Henle):


Secco does mean 'dry', so can be used just to indicate that - 'play in a dry fashion'. This could mean staccato, but generally that would be indicated using actual staccato (either the word, or the dots). Exactly what 'dry' means for a given piece of music is a little bit up to interpretation, but I'd expect a certain unadorned-ness (perhaps in comparison to the surrounding music).
The other piano-specific meaning of secco is that it indicates the opposite of arpeggio - that is, a chord played secco has all notes played at the same time, and not spread. (There's another Music SE question that backs this meaning up.)
Since this is the normal way of playing chords on the piano, it's not usually necessary to explicitly mark them as secco, which is probably why it doesn't show up much - however, it is still seen occasionally. The most famous example I know of for this is at the end of the second movement of Beethoven's Appassionata sonata (edition from IMSLP):

where the right hand is supposed to play its chord all at once (contrast with the left hand playing arpeggiated). In particular, secco here doesn't mean "play without pedal", since there's a pedal mark held across both bars, and it doesn't mean "staccato", since the chord has a fermata over it.
This chord is often miswritten in older non-urtext editions to be arpeggiated in the same way as the previous bar, but the original manuscript (also on IMSLP) is very clear that the RH should be secco while the LH is arpeggio:


Francis Poulenc used the corresponding French term sec very frequently in his piano writing. Here are a couple of examples - the opening of the first Improvisation FP 63:

and bars 13-18 of the 7th Nocturne FP 56:

In the second example, note that in bar 14, the marking sec is accompanied by the instruction sans pédale (without pedal), while in bar 17 the sec marking for the lower figures is contrasted with the instruction le chant lié (the melody legato) for the upper part. For examples taken from overall performance indications, the sixth and eighth of the Soirées des Nazelles variations are marked Très vite et sec and Très rapide et bien sec respectively.
(As an aside, quite a few pianists tend towards a rather dry and detached style as a default in Poulenc's music. On the other hand, in Poulenc's own recordings - especially as an accompanist - one often hears the pedal used very liberally indeed. So although he frequently asks for a "sec" effect, nonetheless it should perhaps be seen more as the exception than as the rule.)

I'm mostly discounting examples in the composer's native language, because they didn't use secco for its established connotations, they wrote dry. French gets an honorable mention because one of the forum answers claims that's its origin, but I'd be similarly suspicious if the composer spoke Italian unless particularly influential.

I believe I first came across this term in this sense in Aaron Copland's Appalachian Spring.
I thought that it was applied to the piano part in one of the sections that was cut from the ballet to create the concert suite, but I don't have my score handy to check (the full orchestra version of the full ballet is available in a YouTube score video, but that figure is neither played by the piano nor marked secco).
But the term is certainly applied to the woodwinds and strings at rehearsal 26 of the orchestral suite.
Merriam-Webster online gives "short and very staccato" as the first definition and "accompanied only by the instruments playing the continuo" as the second.
Similarly, the Dolmetsch online music dictionary gives several definitions:

(Italian) staccato
(Italian) plain, unadorned
(Italian) dry, crisp
(Italian) when using a pair of cymbals, and in contrast to the instruction lasciar vibrare, or l.v., secco is a direction to damp them immediately after they have begun to sound
in piano music, release the right pedal

(It mentions the recitativo secco sense elsewhere.)
I'm quite certain that I've seen secco in percussion parts, though I can't remember where.  In addition to cymbals, I think I've also seen it applied to at least one bass drum part, but it's entirely possible that it was a single part for cymbals and bass drum.
My efforts to come up with resources specific to the piano were similarly fruitless to yours.  But given that secco is used to denote a particularly short staccato, it's not really even necessary to specify that it means "without the damper pedal"; it doesn't necessarily need to have any meaning specific to the piano beyond "dry" and "very short," and the implication this has for the pianist's right foot is an implementation detail.

Downvote -- why?

I didn’t downvote but I can’t find an answer in this answer. Seems like a lot of musings on the topic. Quoting a Beethoven Sonata is much more of an answer than this.

@ToddWilcox the downvote was offered before the answer quoting the Beethoven sonata was posted.

The fact that a better answer didn’t exist yet doesn’t mean this was a good answer at the time. Again, there’s no answer in this answer.

@ToddWilcox It was a fine lead when it looked like the answer might be "no." I upvoted.

@the-baby-is-you Totally reasonable to me. As is downvoting.

My bible (Oxford Companion to Music) makes reference to recitative secco.
Precis of this is using an accompaniment that is quite bare - so little that the listener is hardly aware of its existence. Merely enough to keep the recitation in tune/time. Mozart's Figaro comes to mind. Usually harpsicord chords with string bass, until late 18C, when the harpsicord was replaced by a cello, playing arpeggios.
So, basically, dry or staccato. Maybe even 'distanced', more like an echo, but not delayed, if that makes sense. If any pedal would be deployed, it's going to be the 'soft pedal. Never come across it in piano music, though, as other instructions are more apposite.

Good answer to a different question.

@the-baby-is-you - your dv, or the usual unexplained one..?
